# Connect ot Postgresql mikro-orm

Tags: typescript, postgresql, mikro-orm

I want connect to Postgresql database on mikro-orm

using mikro-orm migration:create but error

```
TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at SchemaBuilder.Target.toQuery (D:\Lesson\full-stack\node_modules\knex\lib\interface.js:14:8)
    at SchemaGenerator.dump (D:\Lesson\full-stack\node_modules\@mikro-orm\knex\schema\SchemaGenerator.js:485:29)
    at SchemaGenerator.getUpdateTableFKsSQL (D:\Lesson\full-stack\node_modules\@mikro-orm\knex\schema\SchemaGenerator.js:132:25)
    at SchemaGenerator.getUpdateSchemaSQL (D:\Lesson\full-stack\node_modules\@mikro-orm\knex\schema\SchemaGenerator.js:88:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at Migrator.getSchemaDiff (D:\Lesson\full-stack\node_modules\@mikro-orm\migrations\Migrator.js:163:26)
    at Migrator.createMigration (D:\Lesson\full-stack\node_modules\@mikro-orm\migrations\Migrator.js:60:22)
    at Function.handleCreateCommand (D:\Lesson\full-stack\node_modules\@mikro-orm\cli\commands\MigrationCommandFactory.js:111:21)
    at Function.handleMigrationCommand (D:\Lesson\full-stack\node_modules\@mikro-orm\cli\commands\MigrationCommandFactory.js:74:17)
```

Comment: what is your os

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in latest version of `knex`, if you lock its to resolution to `0.21.6` it will work.

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/